# Stacking three divs and centering them vertically?

Tags: html, css, centering

This question may have already been answered, but I didn't see anything regarding it while searching, and I'm having a hard time understanding the many ways of centering div's.

Basically, I'm building a small portfolio site and would like to have it laid out in a two column format. The left column will house my logo, and the right column will have a series of three links, which I would like to stack vertically and then also center. I cannot for the life of me, figure out the CSS to get this to work. Here's what I have so far:

```
<div class="row main">
        <div class="col-xs-6 leftMain">
            <img src="img/logo.png" class="logo" alt="myName">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 rightMain">
           <div class="resume button"><a href="resume.html" class="btn">Resume</a></div>
           <div class="portfolio button"> <a href="portfolio.html" class="btn">Portfolio</a></div>
           <div class="contact button"><a href="mailto:me@me.com" class="btn">Contact</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And my CSS:

```
.main {
    display: flex;
}

.leftMain {
    display: inline-block;

}

.rightMain {
    display: inline-block;

}

.logo {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.button {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This works reasonably well, but the links in rightMain do not center vertically. As most of the solutions I've looked up involve the display property, I figured I may as well just ask the full question, rather than trying to integrate multiple solutions for different centering problems. I plan on making it responsive eventually, having the right column move beneath the left on smaller windows. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: So the height of the rightMain container is dependent on the height of the logo image?

Comment: what browsers do you need to support

Comment: Yeah, ideally I would like the logo to be 100% height of leftMain, and have that div resize based on the viewing device. rightMain would then need to be the same height as left, and the three links center within that variable height. Gets a bit complicated when planning for all this without a fixed height on the logo.

Comment: edit: I'd like it work on anything that supports css3.

Comment: the part that i think is impossible using css only is the part where you have boxes resume, portfolio, and contact evenly spaced out vertically.

Comment: Would it be bad practice to use javascript to circumvent the whole issue?

Comment: not at all , check out what i posted below. It does look fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/89jyvow0/3/

**Fullscreen**: http://jsfiddle.net/89jyvow0/3/show/

Css:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html, body {
    min-width: 500px;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    font-size: 0;
}
.logo, .cont {
    font-size: 1rem;
    min-height: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
}
.logo {
    position: relative;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
.cont {
    position: relative;
    width: 70%;
}
.logo h1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 3rem;
}
.wrap, .logo h1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.wrap {
    width: 90%;
    min-width: 300px;
}
.wrap .box {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 30px 0px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 2px solid;
    padding: 20px;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-family: helvetica;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the in depth answer! Looks like this should work, with a bit of editing on my part.

Answer (score 0):

```
.rightMain div  {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cnLav23u/

Source: http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/